# How to retain the focus on the selected row in asp gridview

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

hello guys i have an asp gridview inside a div tag to make it scrollable but when i select row becuase of the postback gridview goes to the top again. how can i maintain the postion of this ? this is my div tag

```
<div style="width: 100%; height:200px; overflow: auto; border: solid black; border-radius: 5px; ">

    <asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" 
    DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1" 
    EmptyDataText="There are no data records to display." >
    <Columns>
        <asp:CommandField ShowSelectButton="True" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="studentid" HeaderText="studentid" 
            SortExpression="studentid" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="studname" HeaderText="studname" 
            SortExpression="studname" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="subjectid" HeaderText="subjectid" 
            SortExpression="subjectid" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="grade" HeaderText="grade" SortExpression="grade" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="section" HeaderText="section" 
            SortExpression="section" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="quarter" HeaderText="quarter" 
            SortExpression="quarter" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="totalnumberpt" HeaderText="totalnumberpt" 
            SortExpression="totalnumberpt" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="totalscoreofpt" HeaderText="totalscoreofpt" 
            SortExpression="totalscoreofpt" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="maxscoreofpt" HeaderText="maxscoreofpt" 
            SortExpression="maxscoreofpt" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="percentageofpt" HeaderText="percentageofpt" 
            SortExpression="percentageofpt" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="weightedscorept" HeaderText="weightedscorept" 
            SortExpression="weightedscorept" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="ptrs1" HeaderText="ptrs1" SortExpression="ptrs1" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="ptms1" HeaderText="ptms1" SortExpression="ptms1" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="ptrs2" HeaderText="ptrs2" SortExpression="ptrs2" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="ptms2" HeaderText="ptms2" SortExpression="ptms2" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="ptrs3" HeaderText="ptrs3" SortExpression="ptrs3" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="ptms3" HeaderText="ptms3" SortExpression="ptms3" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="ptrs4" HeaderText="ptrs4" SortExpression="ptrs4" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="ptms4" HeaderText="ptms4" SortExpression="ptms4" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="ptrs5" HeaderText="ptrs5" SortExpression="ptrs5" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="ptms5" HeaderText="ptms5" SortExpression="ptms5" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="ptrs6" HeaderText="ptrs6" SortExpression="ptrs6" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="ptms6" HeaderText="ptms6" SortExpression="ptms6" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="ptrs7" HeaderText="ptrs7" SortExpression="ptrs7" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="ptms7" HeaderText="ptms7" SortExpression="ptms7" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="ptrs8" HeaderText="ptrs8" SortExpression="ptrs8" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="ptms8" HeaderText="ptms8" SortExpression="ptms8" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="ptrs9" HeaderText="ptrs9" SortExpression="ptrs9" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="ptms9" HeaderText="ptms9" SortExpression="ptms9" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="ptrs10" HeaderText="ptrs10" 
            SortExpression="ptrs10" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="ptms10" HeaderText="ptms10" 
            SortExpression="ptms10" />
    </Columns>
</asp:GridView>
<asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource1" runat="server" 
    ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:StConnectionString1 %>" 
    ProviderName="<%$ ConnectionStrings:StConnectionString1.ProviderName %>" 
    SelectCommand="SELECT [studentid], [studname], [subjectid], [grade], [section], [quarter], [totalnumberpt], [totalscoreofpt], [maxscoreofpt], [percentageofpt], [weightedscorept], [ptrs1], [ptms1], [ptrs2], [ptms2], [ptrs3], [ptms3], [ptrs4], [ptms4], [ptrs5], [ptms5], [ptrs6], [ptms6], [ptrs7], [ptms7], [ptrs8], [ptms8], [ptrs9], [ptms9], [ptrs10], [ptms10] FROM [tblpt]">
</asp:SqlDataSource>

<div>
```

Comment: Check out [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3181540/put-focus-back-on-a-gridviews-selected-row-after-postback)

Comment: where to put this dude ?

<input type="text" id="gridviewcell_id" onkeydown="lastcell.value = this.id" />
<input type="hidden" id="lastcell" runat="server" />

he said to put it in onkeydown script code? where is that ?

Comment: Please be more specific, your question is not well understood.

Comment: Where is the `Gridview` code ??

Comment: This [post](https://forums.aspfree.com/net-development-11/set-focus-selected-gridview-row-after-post-back-243894.html)  should help you get over this .

Comment: not working sir . besides hes idea is to maintain the scroll position of the whole page but not the div,